# Egrep maximal repetition operator {,m} not working as expected?

Tags: ubuntu, grep

Basically if I input a command such as `egrep --color=ALWAYS "A{0,10}B"` and then enter a string
such as 'AAAAAB', this gives the desired behavior of  being a match. However if I instead change it to  `egrep --color=ALWAYS "A{,10}B"` it is no longer matching strings like 
the one I gave. In fact I have not been able to come up with a string that matches the one
given. 
Is this unexpected behavior using the {,m} operator, or is my understanding of that operator not correct, as to me {0,10} should be the same behavior as {,10}. This is running on a bash shell with Ubuntu Linux 10.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an old bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grep/+bug/460985